# Doubly Linked List - Segmentation Faults - C

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement a doubly linked list that acts like a queue (I want it to act like queue).

[EDIT]

When I add nodes to the list (e.g 5 nodes) and empty the list (delete all elements) and try to add another node to the list again, it gives me a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

```
linkedlist.h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct node{
    int d;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct linkedlist{
    int size;
    struct node *first;
    struct node *last;
}linkedlist;




 linkedlist.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "linkedlist.h"

linkedlist* createList(){
    linkedlist* myList = (linkedlist*)calloc(1,sizeof(linkedlist));
    myList->first = NULL;
    myList->last = NULL;
    myList->size =0;

    return myList;

}

static node* createNode(int n){
    node *myNode = (node*)calloc(1,sizeof(node));

    myNode->d = n;

    myNode->prev = NULL;
    myNode->next = NULL;

    return myNode;
}

void insertNode(linkedlist* l, int num){
    node *temp, *newNode;

    newNode = createNode(num);

    if (l->size == 0){
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->prev = NULL;

        l->first = newNode;
        l->last = newNode;

        l->size++;

    }

    else{
        temp = l->first;
        while (temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }   

        newNode->prev = temp;
        temp->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        l->size++;

    }


}

int deleteNode(linkedlist* l){
    node *temp = calloc(1,sizeof(node));

    if (l->first ==NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    else if (l->size ==1){

        free(l->first);
        l->first= NULL;
        l->last = NULL;


        l->size--;

    }

    else if (l->size > 1){
        temp = l->first;
        l->first = temp->next;          

        free(temp);
    }


}

void display(linkedlist *l){
    node *temp = calloc(1,sizeof(node));
    temp = l->first;

    if (temp == NULL){
        printf("The list is empty\n");
    }
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("-> %d ", temp->d);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
int main(){

    linkedlist *myList = createList();

    int choice, temp=0, numb;
    printf("(1) Insert \n (2) Delete \n");

    for (temp; temp<10; temp++){
    printf("Choice :");
    scanf ("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice) {
        case 1: {
            printf("Enter a Number: ");
            scanf("%d", &numb);
            insertNode(myList, numb);
            display(myList);
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
             deleteNode(myList);
            display(myList);
            break;

        }
    }

    }       
}
```

Comment: `malloc()`ating memory in a `delete()` function is more than counterintuitive (and is then accompanied by a nice little memory leak). Casting the return value of `malloc()` is an error, so is using `sizeof(TYPE)` instead of `sizeof(*pointer)` when allocating memory. Stylistic side note: unless in the form `foo_bar` (or `foo_bar_t` as seen in POSIX), lowercase typenames are a bad idea with regards to readability.

Comment: not sure why you loop to end of the list when you already have a last ptr? also use calloc instead of malloc to get everything initialized to 0 and finally don't cast the return value of malloc/calloc

Answer (score 2):

In your delete node function:

```
else if (l->size > 1){
        temp = l->first;
        l->first = NULL;       //this is problem
        l->first->next = NULL;
        temp->next = l->first;

        l->first->prev = NULL;
```

You are assigning `l->first = NULL` and then accessing it in next statement `l->first->next = NULL;`, which will fail and give you segmentation fault.

Also, when `l->size == 1` you should also set `l->first = NULL` after freeing it.

Answer (score 1):

In the deleteNode you leave first pointing to freed memory if the size is 1

It should be:

```
else if (l->size ==1){
    free(l->first);
    l->first = NULL;
    l->last = NULL;
    l->size--;
}
```

Also temp is a pointer you don't need to allocate memory for it with malloc

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears when access to a "NULL" position. Let's revise the code:

```
temp = l->first;
l->first = NULL;        // here, you set l->first = 0
l->first->next = NULL;  // here, you access to 0->next: this is not correct.
temp->next = l->first;
```

Change it for:

```
temp = l->first;
l->first = temp->next;
delete temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int deleteNode(linkedlist* l){
    node *temp= (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)) ;

    if (l->first ==NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    else 
{
temp= l->first;
l->first= temp->next;
l->first->previous= temp;
l->size--;
free(l->first->previous);
}
}
```